# Getting empty response from http get request

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js

I develop a web application with MEAN stack. Nodejs is use to create the server and to connect Mongodb.  I need to show json data in the front-end from this url "http://www.booking.com/autocomplete?lang=en-us&aid=304142&term=tha" then add it in mongodb. So i have been using http service of angularjs but getting an empty response while browser is showing it perfectly fine.
I have tried adding headers and every user-agent. I have tried in different browsers(Chrome , firefox). Even python gets non-empty json. Its not working only in angularjs. Here is the code-

```
var app = angular.module('scrapApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('httpCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.search = function(){
        $http({
            method : 'GET',
          url : "http://www.booking.com/autocomplete?lang=en-us&aid=304142&term=tha"
        }).then(function mySucces(response) {
            $scope.data = response.data.city;
        }, function myError(response) {
            $scope.data = response;
        });
    };
}]);
```

Can you guys help me to figure out the problem?

Comment: Is "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." exception is coming in the console of the developer tool?

Comment: No and i think its a response header but not sure. Actually i don't know much about CORS.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
var app = angular.module('scrapApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('httpCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.data = [];
    var ajaxResponse = $http.get('http://www.booking.com/autocomplete?lang=en-us&aid=304142&term=tha');
    ajaxResponse.success(function(response, status1, headers, config) 
    {
        $scope.data = response.data.city;
    }).error(function(response) 
    {
         $scope.data = response;
    });
}]);
```

Comment: This doesn't work either.By the way this the syntax for AngularJS v1.3.20. I'm using AngularJS v1.4.8. Got this from http://techfunda.com/howto/562/http-get-server-request